# multi row header on Google Visualizations

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to create a DataTable with a multi row header. I'll exemplify here:

```
|               2008           |           2009          |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    price      |   qty.       |    price    |   qty     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     93993     |  34434       |     34244   |   3434    |
.....
```

The years headers can be fixed as I don't want to do sorting by that.
Is there a way to do that in Google Visualizations?

**Update**

Attaching it with JS does NOT work, and it will disappear when sorting is done.

```
$(".google-visualization-table-table").prepend("<tr class='google-visualization-table-tr-head'><td colspan='4'>something</tr>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it cannot be do in googleVisualizations so I did it using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Try using html table in **Column Label** and setting **allowHtml:true** in options.

Here is a sample work around,(not the exact requirement for you).
This may give you some insights to build it.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', '<table align="center" width="100%"><tr><td colspan="2">Year1</td></tr> <tr><td>price</td> <td>qty</td></tr></table>');
        data.addColumn('number', '<table align="center" width="100%"><tr><td colspan="2">Year2</td></tr> <tr><td>price</td> <td>qty</td></tr></table>');
        data.addRow([{v: 1, f: '<table align="center" width="100%"><tr><td>93993</td> <td>34434</td></tr></table>'},
                     {v: 2, f: '<table align="center" width="100%"><tr><td>34244</td> <td>3434</td></tr></table>'} ]);
        data.addRow([{v: 2, f: '<table align="center" width="100%"><tr><td>93995</td> <td>34435</td></tr></table>'},
                     {v: 2, f: '<table align="center" width="100%"><tr><td>34245</td> <td>3435</td></tr></table>'} ]);
        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, allowHtml:true });
         }
      </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='table_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you have pre/appended it back after a click event on your table's sort row (row=0)?

Comment: did not tried. probably it will disappear as well after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable sorting if that option is available. To disable sort, pass `'sort': 'disable'` to the `draw()` method.

Comment: I did not want to disable the sorting, just to have extra headers